# 'Symlink' a github repository

Tags: github

Is it possible to 'symlink' to a github repository? That is, have a github repository at github.com/user1/symlink_to_project seamlessly point to github.com/user2/another_project? The use case is an organization that wants to link to an existing project that already has numerous issues, stars, etc. I'm not sure what the proper term for this would be in github parlance, although I've searched for mirror, link, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to "symlink" a repository, but likely what you want to do is transfer the repository to an Organization account.

More info here: https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/

> **What's transferred with a repository?**
>
> When you transfer a repository, its issues, wiki, stars, and watchers are also transferred.

Answer (score 0):

that's basically what git submodules are: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

you can do it, but if you are going to use submodules you are usually going to have a bad time in the long run.